# Format Spring:message argument

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How can I format the arguments of my `<spring:message>`?

I have a message like this:

```
 message.myMessage=this is {0} my message {1} with {2} multiple arguments
```

My jsp has the following:

```
<spring:message code="message.myMessage" 
                arguments="<fmt:formatNumber value='${value1}' currencySymbol='$' type='currency'/>,${value2},${value3}" 
                htmlEscape="false"/>
```

which doesn't display `value1`, which is a number I would like formatted.

I am not sure I can add the fmt tag inside the argument list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `arguments` attribute of `<spring:message>` can contain JSP EL expressions, but not JSP tags.

Try un-nesting it. You can assign the result of `<fmt:formatNumber>` to a variable, e.g.

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="formattedValue1" value='${value1}' currencySymbol='$' type='currency'/>
<spring:message code="message.myMessage" arguments="${formattedValue1},${value2},${value3}" htmlEscape="false"/>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  FYI I needed to change the argumentSeperator to '|' because a formatted currency has commas and will seperate the numbers once formatted.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Assign the formatted number to a variable then use it in your spring message tag :

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${value1}"
                    var="value4"
                   type="currency"/>

<spring:message code="message.myMessage"
           arguments="${value4},${value2},${value3}"
          htmlEscape="false"/>
```